# Closure example analysis

Tags: javascript

so I would like to analyze a closure example, but i'm not sure if my reasoning is correct, so i'm wondering if someone could let me know if i'm right.

```
var gLogNumber, gIncreaseNumber, gSetNumber;
function setupSomeGlobals() {
    // Local variable that ends up within closure
    var num = 42;
    // Store some references to functions as global variables
    gLogNumber = function() { console.log(num); }
    gIncreaseNumber = function() { num++; }
    gSetNumber = function(x) { num = x; }
}

setupSomeGlobals();
gIncreaseNumber();
gLogNumber(); // 43
gSetNumber(5);
gLogNumber(); // 5

var oldLog = gLogNumber;

setupSomeGlobals();
gLogNumber(); // 42

oldLog() // 5
```

Ok so in the line `setupSomeGlobals();` we call our function which contains three methods.

Next we  call `gIncreaseNumber();`. Cool, so now `num - > 43`, then we log it, to get 43 as expected!

Now things are getting boring, so lets set this `num` to another value. Say 5 as per the line `gSetNumber(5);` Now `num = 5` , and of course we log it to get `5`.

Now heres where things get *trippy* for me. So we say hey, lets give this variable `oldLog` a method with the same property as `glogNumber`. Alright,fair enough.

So we call `setupSomeGlobals()`, and all the stuff we just did like increasing the number and setting the number previously gets overwritten since the code goes back to `var num = 42` ( Ok, this is what I'm not sure about)

Now if we `gLobNumber()`, we get `42`, because with my reasoning everything gets reset to the beginning, where `var num = 42`. Nice!

So now we call `oldLog()` which is pointing to `gLogNumber`. Great so this should be `42` since everything got reset when we did `setupSomeGlobals()`, but this outputs `5`. Erm *whats* going on?

Comment: Calling `setupSomeGlobals()` doesn't *change* the `num` variable, it creates a new closure with its own `num` variable. `oldLog` doesn't get overwritten - it still holds a reference to the previous `gLogNumber` function, which is still using the previous closure.

Comment: So since I set oldLog = gLobNumber BEFORE I said setupSomeGlobals(). We didn't overwrite that property, since before I called setupSomeGlobals, oldLog pointed to 5?

Comment: `oldLog` doesn't point directly to `5`, it refers to a function that has access to the first closure with the `num` variable that is `5`. The only thing each call to `setupSomeGlobals()` overwrites is what the three global variables refer to. (By the way, it's not really a "property": objects have properties. It's just a variable that in this case refers to a function.)

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly what a closure is because you set a reference to a function inside setupSomeGlobals()

```
var oldLog = gLogNumber;
```

When you called setupSomeGlobals() the second time the functions (gLogNumber, etc..) got recreated and now they have access to the new num which is 42

meanwhile the oldLog have access to the variables when setupSomeGlobals() was called for the first time.

For a better understanding of closures check [this](http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/#48) tutorial by John Reisg.

Comment: it's not "their values in that point in time", it's an ongoing reference to the variables, where the values could change. (As demonstrated by calling the increment and set functions.)